# Snowflake external stage with multiple urls

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-connector

I am creating an external stage, I want it to be based on 2 URLs.

**PROBLEM 1**

```
url1 = s3://bucket1/f1/2022/2/
url2 = s3://bucket1/f3/2022/2/

create or replace stage ext_stage url = ??????????
file_format=data_format
storage_integration=s3_integration;
```

How can I give 2 URLs in the external stage command? Is it possible?

**PROBLEM 2**

Also, I need to form the URLs.

I am thinking to use a procedure for it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_url()
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE SCALA
  RUNTIME_VERSION = '2.12'
  HANDLER = 'C.run'
  PACKAGES = ('com.snowflake:snowpark:latest')
  AS
  $$
    import java.util.Calendar
    object C{
      def run(session: com.snowflake.snowpark.Session): String = {
         try {
            val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
            val year =cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            var month =cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1
            return "s3://bucket1/folder1/" + year + "/"+ month + "/"
           }
         catch {
              case e: Throwable => println("Not able to for url")
              return "Failed"
             }
      }
    }
  $$;

create or replace stage ext_stage url = call get_url()
file_format=data_format
storage_integration=s3_integration;
```

It is failing and I can not call the function. How can I call it?

Comment: stage is 1 to 1 with a bucket as far as I know

Comment: might be able to use one URL in the stage for `s3://bucket1/` and then use the "pattern" option to match both `f1/2022/2/` and `f3/2022/2/`